# Using libnoise in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks, libraries

I'm trying to use `libnoise` in a CodeBlocks project but I'm having trouble linking the library.

Here's my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <noise/noise.h>

using namespace noise;

int main(int argv, char *argc[]) {

    module::Perlin myModule;

    return 0;

}
```

And the build log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LD:\Development\libnoise\bin -o bin\Debug\NoiseTest.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -m32 -lmingw32  D:\Development\libnoise\bin\libnoise.lib -mwindows
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
D:/Development/NoiseTest/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `noise::module::Perlin::Perlin()'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5noise6module6PerlinD1Ev':
D:/Development/libnoise/include/noise/module/perlin.h:160: undefined reference to `vtable for noise::module::Perlin'
D:/Development/libnoise/include/noise/module/perlin.h:160: undefined reference to `noise::module::Module::~Module()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I have `libnoise.lib` added to **Linker Settings > Link Libraries**, I have the `libnoise.dll` in my project directory and I have the bin directory added under **Search Directories > Linker**, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: `libnoise.lib` if that was compiled with Visual Studio it may not work.

Comment: Thanks, I compiled the libnoise source and it seems to be working now.